# Linking to questions outside of a site

Tags: feature-request, questions, linked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Also display other SE-site links as linked-questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/also-display-other-se-site-links-as-linked-questions)

If you [link to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82021/89035) on the same site it appears in a table on the right hand side:

[image: Linked Question Table]

How ever if you [link to a question outside of the site](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/256/4) (even within the SE Network) it does not.

There is a natural overlap with some sites and it would be useful to be able to reference other sites, for instance in [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/897/4) about the age of the universe might link to a question on [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5320/2579).